# Reflection to add css class to body tag c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have masterpage which has runat="server" & Id set on body tag. see below

```
<body id="MasterPageBodyTag" runat="server">
```

code behind on masterpage  I've added the following code:

```
    public HtmlGenericControl BodyTag
{
    get { return MasterPageBodyTag; }
    set { MasterPageBodyTag = value; }
}
```

now I want to add css class to body tag from Class1.cs file in App_code folder.

On the .aspx am passing the master page control using the following code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backend.FindPage((PageTemp)this.Master);

}
```

Now on Class1.cs I have the following

```
  public static void FindPage(Control mp)
{

    Page pg = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;


    PropertyInfo inf = mp.GetType().GetProperty("BodyTag");
```

}

I want to  add the following to found BodyTag

```
 //      BodyTag.Attributes.Add("class", "NewStyle");
```

But can't seem to find a way to add atrribute or cast the inf to HtmlGenericControl.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can't you do it client-side with jQuery or similar?

Comment: Is this any use? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95438/Changing-A-Master-Page-Body-Tag-s-CSS-Class-for-Di

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than having a dependency on the Master Page type, I'd simply use FindControl to search for the body element by Id.  Assuming the body tag is on your top-level Master page, and also assuming you may be using nested master pages, it would look something like:

```
private static MasterPage GetTopLevelMasterPage(Page page)
{
    MasterPage result = page.Master;
    if (page.Master == null) return null;

    while(result.Master != null)
    {
        result = result.Master;
    }

    return result;
}

private static HtmlGenericControl FindBody(Page page)
{
    MasterPage masterPage = GetTopLevelMasterPage(page);
    if (masterPage == null) return null;
    return masterPage.FindControl("MasterPageBodyTag") as HtmlGenericControl;
}

private void UpdateBodyCss()
{
    HtmlGenericControl body = FindBody(this);
    if(body != null) body.Attributes.Add(...);
}
```

You could even remove the dependency on the id by searching for an `HtmlGeneric` control with a tag name of "body":

```
private static HtmlGenericControl FindBody(Page page)
{
    MasterPage masterPage = GetTopLevelMasterPage(page);
    if (masterPage == null) return null;
    foreach(Control c in masterPage.Controls)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl g = c as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (g == null) continue;
        if (g.TagName.Equals("body", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return g;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I tried using the solution @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19386/Adding-attributes-to-the-lt-body-tag-when-using-Ma but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I used this and worked for the tags but what might be the reason that cause the controls and forms of ContentPlaceHolder doesn't load even in  page source?

Comment: to be more specifec, I actually used the solution in a class named _Culture with Inherits System.Web.UI.Page then I call this in aspx pages like Public Class _Default   Inherits _Culture

Comment: Oh, I got it .. sorry, that was because I've added updating code to the Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture() not Page_Load

Answer (score 1):

You need the add the following on the aspx file:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Your_Master_Page.Master" %>
```

and then you can do at the .cs of your page:

```
Master.BodyTag.Attributes.Add("class", "NewStyle");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing seems a bit convoluted and there are probably easier ways to deal with this.

To answer your question, you don't need to use reflection. You can simply cast the parameter you're passing to `FindPage` to the master page type you've created.

You haven't specified the type name of your master page so I'll give it the name `MyMasterPage`.

So `FindPage` should look like:

```
public static void FindPage(Control mp)
{
    var masterPage = mp as MyMasterPage;
    if (mp != null)
    {
        mp.BodyTag.Attributes.Add("class", "NewStyle");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use FindControl with an Id rather than taking a dependency on the MasterPage type.

Comment: I get the following error doing it this way: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Joe: An even better idea :-)

Comment: @Chris: the exception you're getting suggests that `MasterPageBodyTag` is null. Check that it's being set correctly, or better yet, use Joe's suggestion!